# How to animate an element inside a List Item in Nativescript?

Tags: animation, nativescript

I'm trying to animate an element inside a list item when another item is tapped, but I can't fin a way to get it.

```
<Repeater items="{{ feedItems }}">
    <Repeater.itemTemplate>
        <GridLayout>

            <GridLayout rows="1*,1*, 1*">

                <GridLayout columns="4*,22*">
                    ...
                </GridLayout>

                <GridLayout row="2">
                    ...
                    <Image col="2" verticalAlignment="bottom" tap="showElementAndAnimate" />
                </GridLayout>
            </GridLayout>

            <GridLayout cssClass="ElementToShow" columns="1*,1*">
                <GridLayout rows="1*,1*,1*" col="1" cssClass="ElementToAnimate">
                    ...
                </GridLayout>
            </GridLayout>
        </GridLayout>
    </Repeater.itemTemplate>
</Repeater>
```

The problem is to get the element to animate after tap since there is a repeater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is:

1. Add a attribute (or Id) to your first parent GridLayout.
2. Add id to the GridLayout that you want to animate (in your case - GridLayout with cssClass="ElementToAnimate").
3. Access the Image, which you want to tap on, from the **args** in the function **showElementAndAnimate**.
4. Then get the Image parent until you reach the parent with the already specified attribute (from point 1).
5. When the correct GridLayout is reached, use the function **getViewById** to get the GridLayout you want to animate (the one with the id from point 2.).
6. After you get the element, you can animate it.

Comment: Good to know that I can put a loaded event inside the itemTemplate, but the problem is that I wanna animate the item A when the item B is Tapped

Comment: Hey @Victor, I updated my answer. Let me know if you haven't made it clear enough to change it again.